# Code is executing process that should have been denied in the initial statement and i dont know why

Tags: python

so i have a data set that contains data similar to: (Left:date, Middle: value, Right:time difference between dates).
[image]

I am developing a code that will scan this data set and if the first value in the right column is bigger than 1 and the successive ones are less than 1, then get me the max value(middle) and tell me the date it happened and put those in a new list. So in the above example, it should check the first 5 rows, find the max value to be 13.15 and tell me the date it happened and store it in a new list. However, my code is not doing this, in fact sometimes is actually produces duplicates and im having trouble finding out why. Code is below:

```
list_final_multiple = []

for i in range(0,len(file_dates_list)): #gets all of the rest of the data
    n = 1
    if (file_gap_list[i] > 1 or i == 0) and file_gap_list[i+n] <= 1:
        while ((i + n) < len(file_dates_list)) and (file_gap_list[i + n] <= 1):
            n = n + 1
        max_value = (max(file_hs_list[i:i + n]))
        max_value_location = file_hs_list.index(max_value)
        list_final_multiple.append([file_dates_list[max_value_location], file_hs_list[max_value_location]])
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to verify that, for example, `file_gap_list[i]` has the value you expect it to have, at all times?

Comment: You have given only part of the program. What are the values of file_dates_list, file_gap_list & file_hs_list ?

Comment: the values of file_dates_list and file_gap_list and hs are stored each on an excel spreadsheet, if it will help i will try and upload them

Comment: and yes ive just done a verification that file_gap_list[i[ prints out the expected value @Karl